# I want to output the comment list of the previous and next articles with Wordpress, but it fails.　Do I need to use a database?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to view comments from previous and next articles in my single.php.
Currently it is displayed as follows in all articles.

・aaaaaaa
・aaaaaaa

**single.php**

```
<?php
$nextID = $post_ids[$current + 1]; 
$next2ID = $post_ids[$current + 2]; 
echo '<ul>';

//One Article comment
$args = ['post_id' => $nextID, ];
$comments = get_comments($args);
if (empty($comments)) {
$comment = 'No comments';
} else {
$comment = $comments[0]->comment_content;
}
echo "<li>{$comment}</li>";

//Two Article comment
$args = ['post_id' => $next2ID, ];
$comments = get_comments($args);
if (empty($comments)) {
$comment = 'No comments';
} else {
$comment = $comments[0]->comment_content;
}
echo "<li>{$comment}</li>";
echo '</ul>';

?>
```

Comment: Question is unclear to me. Wordpress uses a database already.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I want to display the previous and next article comments in php without using phpmyadmin.